# Checkedlistbox with Combobox for every Item

Tags: vb.net

I want my programm to display a Combobox next to Item in Checkedlistbox after User marks the checkbox.
This Combobox should be created within a for Loop (there is always different amount of items in checkedlistbox, depends on user input).

My code so far to display Items in Checkedlistbox:

```
 For j = 0 To db3._dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        If db3._dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("AUFTRAGNUMMER") = db._dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(selectedIndex)(0) Then
            CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(db3._dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("ANZPOS") & "   :   " & db3._dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("ARTIKEL") & "   :   " & db3._dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("BEZEICHNUNG"))
        End If
    Next
```

So next to that a combobox should appear if checkbox is checked.
Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: And what happens when the user scrolls the CheckedListBox? I think you should consider using something like a DataGridView instead. You can add a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` and a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to it and enable/disable the ComboBox in a certain cell based on the value of the CheckBox in the same row.

Comment: The suggestion by @41686d6564 is absolutely what you should do, even if there isn't any scrolling.

Comment: You can even add and remove the `ComboBox` controls as boxes are checked and unchecked if you want, by assigning a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` or `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` to the appropriate coordinates in the grid. Before you ask, it's not for us to explain how to do that for you. If you do choose to go a different way then you should delete this question as no longer relevant, do the appropriate research on the new approach and make your best effort, then post back if and when you encounter an issue with that.

Comment: I was not sure of DataGridView but it works perfectly for what I need. Thanks for quick advice!